# Cannot find a way to convert an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC view to string in Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API that I need to take an HTML template (like a view), pass it an object (line a model) and get the resulting HTML as a string.

My project doesn't use Razor or views so how would I accomplish this?

Comment: Are these "HTML templates" just raw strings/text, or are they (precompiled) Razor views?

Comment: @Dai I'm hoping to use something like a Razor view to fill in some of the html dynamically. It can be any rendering engine however not just Razor. I just assumed it would be more native than others. I'm trying to generate a pdf from html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For how to convert the view to string, you can refer to the code below:

```
public class Helper
{
    public static string RenderRazorViewToString(Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
    {
        controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            IViewEngine? viewEngine =
                controller.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ICompositeViewEngine)) as
                    ICompositeViewEngine;
            ViewEngineResult? viewResult = viewEngine?.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName, false);

            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
                controller.ControllerContext,
                viewResult.View,
                controller.ViewData,
                controller.TempData,
                sw,
                new HtmlHelperOptions()
            );
            viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Call it by:

```
var view = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "ViewName", model);
```

---

A simple demo about how to render the html string in another view:

Model

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class RenderView
{
    public string HtmlString { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new Test() { Id = 1, Name = "aa" };
    var view = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "Privacy", model);
    return View(new RenderView() { HtmlString=view});
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model RenderView
@Html.Raw(Model.HtmlString)
```

Privacy.cshtml:

```
@model Test
<h1>@Model.Id</h1>
<h2>@Model.Name</h2>
```

Comment: I had to switch from `BaseController` to `Controller` to get this to compile and now getting the error that `viewResult` is null because `viewEngine` is null.

Comment: Hi @user3953989, pls share enough code to give more explanations. Thx.

Comment: I had to add `builder.Services.AddRazorPages();` to get the razor engine added. Now it works but the model I pass it is null in the view. Stepping through the debugger shows `controller.ViewData.Model = model;` has the correct value.

Comment: Pls share enough code to reproduce the issue. Are you sure you use the ASP.NET Core MVC instead of Razor Pages?